# Can I disable web editing of a Rendering Variant Reference field/Field

Tags: sxa

Is it possible within SXA to prevent web editing of a particular field?  ie. I don't want them editing the value of the field highlighted below in Experience Editor, only in Content Editor.

[image]

I did notice the Is editable checkbox - but that just makes it read only instead of editable still in the content editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will uncheck the `Is editable` checkbox in particular item, [Rendering Variants](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-rendering-variant.html) will disable edition of that field in Experience Editor. So yes you can disable web editing of particular filed which are rendered using Rendering Variants in Experience Editor.

Keep in mind that Rendering Variants has nothing to do with Content Editor.

Comment: Oh great! I thought something weird had happened when I last tried using this checkbox and I found I couldn't edit it anywhere any more.  But is doing the trick - thanks :)